# jQuery change input box by preceding label

Tags: jquery, forms

I have the following bit of HTML:

```
<label>First Name</label><input name="Question62" type="text" value="" />
```

Unfortunately because I am creating several forms, the "name" of the input box will change however the "label" contents will stay the same ("First Name").

Is there a way to change the input value by the preceding label? (instead of an id tag in the input box)?

[Edit] Answer given below, code provided in case anyone needs it:

```
var firstName = $("label:contains('First Name')");
firstName.next('input').val(obj.first_name);
```

Comment: If you found the answer, then put it in answers' section, not inside the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want jquery `.next()` method.

http://api.jquery.com/next/

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
var labelContent = "First Name";
$('label:contains('+labelContent+') ~ :text')​.val( 'Some value' )
```

Comment: This puts the label contents in the text box, really I just want to grab the input box closest to the label.